# adding event listeners to objects in html canvas

Tags: canvas, event-handling, graphics2d

How do I attach event listeners for mouseover and click to objects on the HTML Canvas.
I have created an object using "graphics2d" on the canvas but don't see how to do this last step.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way of adding an event handler to an item drawn on the canvas, as it is just a drawing - no interaction is possible.

However, it is possible to catch the mouse events on the canvas itself, then by keeping reference to all objects drawn on the canvas in javascript, loop through each and get the co-ordinates and check whether the mouse event happened over that object, at which point you could call your own function that specifies what to do when a specific object receives a mouse event.

There is a lot of code out there that works in this way, an example I worked on a few years ago is: http://www.diagramo.com

Answer (score 0):

`jp_doodle` supports events for canvas objects.

Please see the Javascript quick reference under "part 3: events and mutations"

https://aaronwatters.github.io/jp_doodle/quick_references/Dual%20canvas%20Javascript%20quick%20reference.html